# Returning from an async method in a SignalR Core hub

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub

I have an ASP .Net Core 2.2 Web API. In it I am using SignalR. In my hub, I need to save messages to the database, so I am getting an instance of DbContext, and because I am calling the SaveChangesAsync() method of DbContext, I need to make the method async. So, from

```
public Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
{
    return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
}
```

I now have

```
    public async Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
            Message newMessage = new Message()
            {
                Body = message,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
            };

            dbContext.Messages.Add(newMessage);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
```

However, now I'm getting this error:

**Since 'ChatHub.SendMessageToAll(string)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?**

Which makes sense, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below:

```
return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```